# How to use Nikkou (newbie Ruby question!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use Nikkou in a Ruby/Rails class but I don't fully understand the very basics. The Nikkou documentation suggests that you just need to add the gem to the Gemfile and you're away... but I can't make any of the Nikkou additions to Nokogiri work for me.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `text_includes' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x00007fe718540a90>):`
```

There must be some step I'm missing that's so obvious it isn't even mentioned in the documentation. Can anybody enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
require 'nikkou'
```

Comment: I actually did think of that but I just see `cannot load such file -- nikkou` if I do that? I can see nikkou in `gem list` though...

Comment: Ah, I think restarting the rails server on top of that may have done the trick. Much obliged